# Polymorphic types in records

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that reads raw bytes from a file, "casts" it to a "plain" type, then sorts it.

In order to do this, I need to tell the sort how it should interpret the binary data - i.e., what the type of the binary data is.

In order for it to be "binary" data, in the sense of "I can treat this data as raw bits, as I read and write it from disk", the type of the data must be Binary and Bits.
And, to sort it, it must be a member of Ord.

Any type constrained these ways should be sortable.

As a little hack, in order to pass the type to the sort function, I am passing an inhabitant of the type instead. (If there's a way to pass the type itself and achieve the results, I'd love to know.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Binary.Get
import Data.Binary.Put

type Sortable = forall a. (Bits a, Binary a, Ord a) => a

data SortOpts = SortOpts { maxFiles :: Int
    , maxMemory :: Integer
    , maxThreads :: Int
    , binType    :: Sortable
}

defaultOpts = SortOpts { maxFiles = 128
    , maxMemory = 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000
    , maxThreads = 4
    , binType = 0 :: Word32
};

putBinaryValues :: Binary a => Handle -> [a] -> IO ()
putBinaryValues out vals = do
    let bytes = runPut . mapM_ put $ vals
    BL.hPut out bytes

binaryValues :: (Binary a, Bits a) => a -> Handle -> IO [a]
binaryValues t inf = do 
    size <- hFileSize inf
    let cast = runGet (genericReplicateM (size `div` byteWidth) get)
    cast . BL.fromChunks . (:[]) <$> BS.hGetContents inf
    where genericReplicateM n = sequence . (DL.genericReplicate n)
          byteWidth = fromIntegral $ (bitSize t) `div` 8
```

But this doesn't compile. Apparently Haskell insists that all of the values of the record are concrete types. At least, that's what I'm gathering from the error message:

```
Could not deduce (a ~ Word32)
    from the context (Bits a, Ord a, Binary a)
        bound by a type expected by the context:
             (Bits a, Ord a, Binary a) => a
at ...
    `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context: (Bits a, Ord a, Binary a) => a
```

So, how *could* I achieve this generalization?

EDIT:

I wanted to use record update syntax to "configure" the sort. E.G.:

```
configure = defaultOpts -- and exporting that
```

and later

```
let myOpts = configure{ binType = 42 :: Word16 }
```

But this doesn't work, and I can't quite understand why, unless it's just NYI.

```
Record update for insufficiently polymorphic field: binType :: a
In the expression: configure {binType = words !! 0}
In an equation for `o': o = configure {binType = words !! 0}
In the expression:
  do { inTestHandle <- inTest;
       words <- testRandomWords;
       putBinaryValues inTestHandle $ take 100 words;
       seekBeg inTestHandle;
       .... }
```

So, does my client code just have to copy the values out of defaultOpts piecemeal and make a new record every it wants to reconfigure the sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ExistentialQuantification`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#existential-quantification) in your `SortOpts` type. The following compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Data.Bits
import Data.Word
import Data.Binary
import Data.Binary.Get
import Data.Binary.Put

data SortOpts = forall a. (Bits a, Binary a, Ord a) => SortOpts
    { maxFiles   :: Int
    , maxMemory  :: Integer
    , maxThreads :: Int
    , binType    :: a
    }

defaultOpts = SortOpts
    { maxFiles = 128
    , maxMemory = 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000
    , maxThreads = 4
    , binType = 0 :: Word32
    }
```

However, note that you cannot use `binType` as a function because it would have a type like `exists a. SortOpts -> a` and you cannot existential types as return values. You can however get the field value by pattern matching, for example

```
test :: SortOpts -> ByteString -> ByteString -> Ordering
test (SortOpts{binType=binType}) bsa bsb = compare a b where
    a = runGet get bsa `asTypeOf` binType
    b = runGet get bsb `asTypeOf` binType
```

This deserializes and compares the two bytestrings using the existential `binType` in the given `SortOpts`.

As you noticed, Haskell's record-update syntax doesn't support existential fields, so you need to do something like this to update `binType`:

```
defaultOpts = SortOpts
    { maxFiles = 128
    , maxMemory = 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000
    , maxThreads = 4
    , binType = 0 :: Word32
    }

alternativeOpts = withBinType (0 :: Word16) $ defaultOpts
    { maxFiles = 256 }

withBinType :: (Bits a, Binary a, Ord a) => a -> SortOpts -> SortOpts
withBinType bt (SortOpts{..}) = SortOpts maxFiles maxMemory maxThreads bt
```

The above uses `RecordWildCards` to make copying the record a bit easier. It's also a handy extension when using the options record later on.

Alternatively, as jozefg suggested, you could use a wrapper type for `binType`. You would use it like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data BinType = forall a. (Bits a, Binary a, Ord a) => BinType a

data SortOpts = SortOpts
    { maxFiles   :: Int
    , maxMemory  :: Integer
    , maxThreads :: Int
    , binType    :: BinType
    }

defaultOpts = SortOpts
    { maxFiles = 128
    , maxMemory = 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000
    , maxThreads = 4
    , binType = BinType (0 :: Word32)
    }

alternativeOpts = defaultOpts
    { binType = BinType (0 :: Word16) }
```

Since `SortOpts` is now just a regular record type you can use all record operations normally. To refer to the unwrapped `binType`, you need to pattern match on the wrapper so the `test` example from before would become (using `RecordWildCards`)

```
test :: SortOpts -> ByteString -> ByteString -> Ordering
test (SortOpts{..}) bsa bsb = case binType of
    BinType bt -> compare a b where
        a = runGet get bsa `asTypeOf` bt
        b = runGet get bsb `asTypeOf` bt
```

Note that all of the above assumes that you have a particular use-case where you need to be able to hide the exact type parameter behind an existential for some reason. Normally, you would just leave the type-parameter in `SortOpts` and constrain it in the functions that use `SortOpts`. I.e.

```
data SortOpts a = SortOpts
    { maxFiles   :: Int
    , maxMemory  :: Integer
    , maxThreads :: Int
    , binType    :: a
    }

test :: (Bits a, Binary a, Ord a) => SortOpts a -> ByteString -> ByteString -> Ordering
test (SortOpts{..}) bsa bsb = compare a b where
    a = runGet get bsa `asTypeOf` binType
    b = runGet get bsb `asTypeOf` binType
```

You can use the `ConstraintKinds` extension to make a shorter alias if needed, as in

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

type BinType a = (Bits a, Binary a, Ord a)

test :: BinType a => SortOpts a -> ByteString -> ByteString -> Ordering
```

Comment: -1, the first example doesnt work, an existential record has escaped type variables. ghci seems to accept it, but try asking for the type of 'binType'

Comment: Which version of GHC? It compiles for me.

Comment: in 7.6 anything that *uses* binType creates an compile time error, however only if you use binType. merely creating the record doesnt trigger the error

Comment: @jozefg: Ah, good point! I added an example how to use the existential field.

Comment: Both of these answers helped me quite a bit, and it was hard to decide which one to accept. In the end, I went with {-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-} in the code, so I accepted this answer.

Comment: Oops, do you have any idea how to get around the "insufficiently polymorphic" problem in record update syntax?

Comment: @masonk You can't, it's the same problem that I explained in my answer, you need something that knows how to be every possible intersection of `Bin`, `Bytes`, and `Ord`

Comment: @jozefg Why can I do this: `myOpts = SortOpts{ maxFiles = (maxFiles defaultOpts), maxMemory = (maxMemory defaultOpts), maxThreads = (maxThreads defaultOpts), binType = 0 :: Word16}`, (and I can), but not `myOpts = defaultOpts{binType = 0 :: Word16}`. Semantically, what is different about those two expressions?

Comment: @masonk In one, you are constructing the type and can choose the implementation, in 2, you are updating a type with something of a different type, an error

Comment: You know that they are the same type, but GHC can't tell because the existential is hiding the concrete type

Comment: What would happen if the type in that record wasn't `Word16`? What would GHC store it as?

Comment: @masonk: There's no real semantic difference, as both cases essentially create a new record. It's just a limitation in the record-update syntax. I updated the answer to show how you could handle updating the existential field or alternatively, how you could use a boxed `binType` field in practice.

Answer (score 8):

#### The Problem

The problem is the `RankNTypes`. Look at `Sortable`, it is a function which will return an arbitrary `a`, where `a` is an instance of `Ord`, `Bits`, and `Bytes`. In other words, you don't have just an instance of the 3 classes there, you have *all* instances there.

`Word32` obviously can't do this, so trying to put it there is an error.

Think of this like `undefined`, `undefined` isn't "some type compatible with `a`", it can be all types. It would be equivalent to saying

```
foo :: a
foo = 1
```

If you want some vocab: `a` is universally quantified, so the caller chooses the implementation. What you want is an existential quantification, where the callee chooses the concrete type.

#### Possible Fixes

So the simplest remedy is

```
data SortOpts a = SortOpts { 
    maxFiles :: Int
    , maxMemory :: Integer
    , maxThreads :: Int
    , binType    :: a
}
```

and constrain `a` on each function

```
 someFun :: (Bits a, Bytes a, Ord a) => SortOpts a -> whatever
```

To ease the typing,

```
 class (Ord a, Bytes a, Bits a) => Sortable a where
 instance (Ord a, Bytes a, Bits a) => Sortable a where
```

Otherwise you'll need to create an existential "boxing" type. Here I use a [GADT](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) to do that.

```
 {-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

 data SortBox where
     Sort :: (Bits a, Bytes a, Ord a) => a -> SortBox
```

and then create instances of `Bits`, `Bytes`, and `Ord` on it simply by unboxing the hidden `a` and operating on it. This let's you box up any type with `Sort` and then use it generically as a `Bits`, `Bytes`, or `Ord`. It's transparent at the type level, but at the value level you must box stuff up which is odd.

```
data SortOpts a = SortOpts { 
    maxFiles :: Int
    , maxMemory :: Integer
    , maxThreads :: Int
    , binType    :: SortBox
}
```

Comment: Thanks joze! I am working through this now. What is the `data SortBox where` construct. How do I create instances of SortBox? I've never seen that before.

Comment: its a gadt, generalized abstract data type, its a ghc specific extension. i'm using it here to create an existential type

Comment: @masonk I added a link